# New Zones of Thought book?

Tags: vernor-vinge, zones-of-thought

I keep [seeing a cover](http://sfmag.hu/files/2012/11/zonesofthought.jpg) for a Vernor Vinge book called Zones of Thought.
Is this an actual book or is this a planned book or neither?

[image: Zones of Thought]

Answer (score 14):

The cover you've seen seems to be from an omnibus edition of [the Zones of Thought series](http://www.goodreads.com/series/52585-zones-of-thought). For whatever reason, the book seems to be available [in the UK](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Zones-Thought-Deepness-Vernor-Omnibus/dp/0575093692/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1364916788&sr=1-1), but not in the US.

[image: cover art]

Comment: Sooo disappointed in this answer (I'm still upvoting it, though)... I was hoping there'd be a new book soon!

Comment: I'm with you, @Beofett.  _Children of the Sky_ sure implies that there's far more story to be told.